# How to know the class label associated for the term in tfidf matrix

Tags: python

I have TFIDF weight matrix. The matrix is like this:

```
(0, 11)   0.238317554822
(0, 34)   0.355850989305
(0, 7)    0.355850989305
(0, 21)   0.238317554822
(0, 16)   0.355850989305
(0, 35)   0.355850989305
(0, 8)    0.355850989305
(0, 17)   0.355850989305
(0, 36)   0.355850989305
(1, 11)   0.238317554822
(1, 21)   0.238317554822
(1, 23)   0.355850989305
(1, 0)    0.355850989305
(1, 24)   0.355850989305
(1, 12)   0.355850989305
(1, 22)   0.355850989305
(1, 25)   0.355850989305
(1, 13)   0.355850989305
(2, 2)    0.27430356415
(2, 18)   0.339992197465
(2, 26)   0.339992197465
(2, 39)   0.339992197465
(2, 3)    0.339992197465
(2, 19)   0.339992197465
(2, 27)   0.339992197465
(2, 4)    0.339992197465
(2, 20)   0.339992197465
(3, 2)    0.27430356415
(3, 40)   0.339992197465
(3, 9)    0.339992197465
(3, 1)    0.339992197465
(3, 5)    0.339992197465
(3, 41)   0.339992197465
(3, 10)   0.339992197465
```

How i can call the the class label for each term in this matrix?

Comment: How do you define "class label"?

Comment: i want to call the class assoicated for each term

Comment: A tf-idf matrix does not perform classification.

Comment: yes i know , i just calculated it to get the weight of terms for the predefined classified documents that i'll use it in training my classifier ,